# how to compile talend open studio in eclipse juno?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, talend

I would make maven eclipse project on top of talend open studio get from talend svn

[talendforge svn](http://talendforge.org/svn/tos/trunk)

i'v readed the guide from talend forge forum:

[http://www.talendforge.org/wiki/doku.php?id=dev:run_from_svn](http://talendforge.org/svn/tos/trunk)

, but at end of procedure i get 100 problem :
- on missing eclipse dependencies
- on missing configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you will be able to compile Talend with Juno version. Talend 5.2 is dependant of Indigo version plugins.

A better tutorial is provided on [Glen Mazza's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/weektal_building_tos_data_integration).
It gives you all dependencies needed for running Talend from source code.

This [post](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12873) on TalendForge will also give you interesting feedback and Post#16 provides a link to Eclipse Indigo prepared package (linux platform).

Comment: my purpose is :to customize the entire talend project and make a maven version

Comment: Yes, of course, but to customize a Talend project, you need to be able to compile it ! Right ? And in order to compile Talend project, you need the right version of Eclipse and its dependencies ;)

Comment: I've Edited my answer for better understanding : I mean, if you want to compile Talend 5.2, you need Talend Indigo with the corresponding dependencies